# Plugin: Fill Record with data (auto generated form)

Tags: plugin-development, records

Is there a way to generate a form based on my record-attributes ? Like a quick and dirty CRUD-Interface to get started ?

And otherwise: where would I create such forms ? Are those Controllers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're asking is if there is any built-in [scaffolding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming)) support in Craft.

If that's the case, then no... you'd have to manually build out the forms and CRUD support.

[Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) does ship with a component called [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/prototype.scaffold#installing-gii) that enables scaffolding, but it's currently not compatible with Craft and we don't support it.